# Create embedded docs with Mongoose and Express

Tags: express, mongoose, pug

Racking my brain to create a embedded document with Mongoose. I get the following error when I submit the form:

**500 CastError: Cast to undefined_method failed for value "comment goes here"**

code:

index.js

```
var db = require( 'mongoose' );
var Todo = db.model( 'Todo' );

exports.create = function(req, res, next){
  new Todo({
      title      : req.body.title,
      content    : req.body.content,
      comments   : req.body.comments,
  }).save(function(err, todo, count){
    if( err ) return next( err );
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

db.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// recursive embedded-document schema
var commentSchema = new Schema();

commentSchema.add({ 
    content  : String   
  , comments : [Comment]
});

var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

var todoSchema = new Schema({
    title      : { type: String, required: true }
  , content    : String
  , comments   : [Comment]
});

var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

Jade form

```
form(action="/create", method="post", accept-charset="utf-8")
  input.inputs(type="text", name="title")
  input.inputs(type="text", name="content")
  input.inputs(type="text", name="comments")
input(type="submit", value="save")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For nested / embedded documents to work you have to use the .push() method.

```js
var Comment = new Schema({
    content    : String
  , comments   : [Comment]
});

var Todo = new Schema({
    user_id    : String
  , title      : { type: String, required: true }
  , content    : String
  , comments   : [Comment]
  , updated_at : Date
});

mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
mongoose.model('Comment', Comment);
```

```js
exports.create = function(req, res, next){
  var todo = new Todo();
      todo.user_id    = req.cookies.user_id;
      todo.title      = req.body.title;
      todo.content    = req.body.content;
      todo.updated_at = Date.now();
      todo.comments.push({ content : req.body.comments });

  todo.save(function(err, todo, count){
    if( err ) return next( err );

    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose models never get involved in schemas. Only basic datatypes and mongoose schemas. Not sure if there are gotchas with a recursive comment schema, but try something like this.

```
var commentSchema = new Schema();

commentSchema.add({ 
  , content  : String   
  , comments : [commentSchema]
});

var todoSchema = new Schema({
  , title      : { type: String, required: true }
  , content    : String
  , comments   : [commentSchema]
});

var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

Comment: I just tried your code and removed the first comma's on the schema. Here's the error I received:

Express
500 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in comment goes here

Comment: Ah yes, so you can't just stick an array of javascript objects into the comments, you need to convert them to mongoose Comment model instances first, then save the Todo with the embedded comments.